# How to change the file chooser to select a file and display it in a list

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jfilechooser, playlist

I am trying to create a playlist gui.
This code shows the JFrame with menubar and the file chooser that appears automatically when run, What do I need to add to make it so the user selects the button to open the file chooser and how can I display the music file after they have selected it? As if it is to display like a playlist so they can select delete, copy etc. Thanks for your help!!

```
public class PlaylistView extends JFrame{    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Playlist");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(800,600);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        //The creation of a menubar
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        //sets menu bar onto the frame
        f.setJMenuBar(mb);

        //New menu items
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");
        JMenu exit = new JMenu("Exit");
        mb.add(file);
        mb.add(edit);
        mb.add(exit);


        JMenuItem addsong = new JMenuItem("Add Song");
        JMenuItem deletesong = new JMenuItem("Delete Song");
        JMenuItem copysong = new JMenuItem("Copy Song");
        file.add(addsong);
        file.add(deletesong);
        file.add(copysong);  

        JMenuItem addplaylist = new JMenuItem("Add Playlist");
        edit.add(addplaylist);
        JMenuItem deleteplaylist = new JMenuItem("Delete Playlist");
        edit.add(deleteplaylist);
        JMenuItem saveplaylist = new JMenuItem("Save Playlist");
        edit.add(saveplaylist);
        JMenuItem copyplaylist = new JMenuItem("Copy Playlist");
        edit.add(copyplaylist);

        //Button actually open to the file chooser
        JButton open = new JButton("Add Song");        
        //Filechooser to add a song in
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
        fc.setDialogTitle("Add Song");
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        if (fc.showOpenDialog(open) == JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG){

        }
        System.out.println("File Selected:" + fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsoluteFile());
    }
}
```

Comment: See [How to use Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) in the Java Tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the files in a list, you can save them in a JList.

```
DefaultListModel mylistmodel = new DefaultListModel();
JList songs= new JList(mylistmodel );

Everytime you select a file, you can call add the item to the list by,

mylistmodel.addElement(songtoAdd); // songtoadd is an object

mylistmodel.insertElementAt(songtoAdd, 0); // to insert songs at specific positions.

mylistmodel.remove(IndexofSong);
```

You can use specific methods for the above activities and then call the appropriate one to perform each action.